# General form of an orthogonal matrix involving angles, sines, and cosines

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, orthogonal-matrices, reflection

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, all orthogonal matrices are one of two forms:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\
-\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix} \text{ or }
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & -\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
$$

for some angle $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. In $\mathbb{R}^3$, all orthogonal matrices are of the form:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\alpha\cos\gamma - \sin\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma & -\sin\alpha\cos\beta & -\cos\alpha\sin\gamma-\sin\alpha\sin\beta\cos\gamma \\
\cos\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma+\sin\alpha\cos\gamma & \cos\alpha\cos\beta & \cos\alpha\sin\beta\cos\gamma-\sin\alpha\sin\gamma \\
\cos\beta\sin\gamma & -\sin\beta & \cos\beta\cos\gamma
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ are angles.

How can I parametrize any orthogonal matrix in $\mathbb{R}^n$ using some number of angles, and the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions?

Is there a recursive formula?

Comment: What's the determinant of that $3\times3$ matrix?

Comment: It appears to be always 1, so perhaps I meant to say to also include the sign flip of one of the rows.

Comment: Or maybe stick to matrices in $\text{SO}(n)$.